# XML to Json with Camel

Tags: java, json, xml, maven, apache-camel

My program should convert XML file format to JSON file format. Im trying to use the marshal command, but I get errors:

> Exception in thread "main"
> org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route
> route1 at: >>>
> Marshal[org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.XmlJsonDataFormat@815b41f]
> <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[file:resource/inbox]] ->
> [Marshal[org.ap... because of Data format 'xmljson' could not be
> created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel
> component is present on the classpath
>
> Caused by:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data format 'xmljson' could not be
> created. Ensure that the data format is valid and the associated Camel
> component is present on the classpath

**Java code**

```
package route;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.XmlJsonDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;

public class CopyToJsonRoute {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Log 4j
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        // create CamelContext
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

        // add our route to the CamelContext
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                // http://www.yr.no/place/Norway/Oslo/Oslo/Oslo/forecast.xml

                XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();
                xmlJsonFormat.setForceTopLevelObject(true);
                from("file:resource/inbox")
                        .marshal(xmlJsonFormat)
                        .to("file:src/main/resources/data/output?autoCreate=true");



            }
        });

        // start the route and let it do its work
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        // stop the CamelContext
        context.stop();
    }
}
```

**Pom file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.yourdomain.subdomain</groupId>
    <artifactId>copy-to-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-alpha2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xom/xom -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xom</groupId>
            <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `camel-xmljson` as dependency in your Maven pom file

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-xmljson</artifactId>
        <version>2.20.0</version>
    </dependency>
```